# A problem in a Type in WCF method

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4

I have this code in WCF service:

```
public void fill_WF(bool flag, int ID, string name)
{            
    DataClasses1DataContext DB1 = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    WF entry = new WF();               
    entry.Values= flag;
    entry.wf_UID = ID;
    entry.wf_name = name;    
    DB1.WFs.InsertOnSubmit(entry);
    DB1.SubmitChanges();
}

public bool get_from_WF(int id)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext DB = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var c = from D in DB.WFs
            where D.wf_ID == 1
            select D.Values;
    return (bool)c.ToList().First();
}
```

The data in the table WF here:
https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=F1FD3CCD21D87C68&id=F1FD3CCD21D87C68%21356&sc=documents

When I'm trying the get_from_WF in WcfTestClient.exe, I got the following error, its internal

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=F1FD3CCD21D87C68&id=F1FD3CCD21D87C68%21355&sc=documents

when I changed the get_from_WF to the following:

```
public bool get_from_WF(int id)
{
    return true;
}
```

it works.

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?  My guess is something didn't work as you expected in get_from_WF.

Comment: I agree with Tim that you may try to look at whether the service throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the DataClasses1DataContext type is a Entity Framework data context. If so the first thing I would check is if the required connection string is present in the web.config for the service.

Adding a [serviceDebug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788993.aspx) behavior with [IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.includeexceptiondetailinfaults.aspx) might give you more info about what the real exception is.